# Multiple seekbar in one java class, need implement each setOnSeekBarChangeListener for each seekbar?

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I need to make multiple seek bar in the same Java class. However, I wonder do we need to set each setOnSeekBarChangeListener for each seek bar? The code seems too long if I am doing so (I need to create 10 seek bar in the same class). Is there any other solution which I can shorten the code? Thank you so much for helping. :)

Below is my code

```
    private SeekBar seekbar,seekbar1;
    private TextView a,b;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.schiassess);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.delubar);
        seekbar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.disorbar);
        a =  findViewById(R.id.a);
        b =  findViewById(R.id.b);


        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                int val = (progress * (seekBar.getWidth() - 2 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
                progress++;
                a.setText("" + progress);
                a.setX(seekBar.getX() + val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 2);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                int val = (progress * (seekBar.getWidth() - 2 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
                progress++;
                b.setText("" + progress);
                b.setX(seekBar.getX() + val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 2);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps it's simple

JUST IMPLEMENT SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener in your class/fragment

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
}
```

You don't have to write new OnSeekBarChangeListener for Every Seekbar...

Just Implement

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

} to your Activity/Fragment..
```

Now you can check for the id and perform action according to it